# How to attach Xib at the bottom of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, xib

I would like to attach a nib file with custom buttons and textfields at the bottom of a tableview. When i scroll the table and it reaches the last cell it must just continues to the attached nib without stopping scrolling. I want to achieve the same action as if its a footer on the tableview. How do i achieve such in objective c. An example or a pointer to a tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: how about using the nib as a cell content? or as a section footer?

Comment: i thought of this idea too however i am not sure how to make the nib the last cell in a tableView

Comment: is the tableview implemented using a storyboard or code?

Comment: yes it is implemented using storyboards

Comment: then I won't be able to help you, I don't use storyboards.. but maybe someone will be better help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article that I had used a while ago to be able to use Xib files in storyboards:

https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d